# Cannot load cached AssetBundle. A file of the same name is already loaded from another AssetBundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load a scene but I am getting the error from title and I simply don't know why because I call Unload(false) on AssetBundle. Can someone help me? Thanks.

```
void Start() {
...
 StartCoroutine (DownloadAndCache());
...
}

IEnumerator DownloadAndCache (){
    // Wait for the Caching system to be ready
    while (!Caching.ready)
        yield return null;

    // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
        using(WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (BundleURL, version)){
            yield return www;

            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;

            bundle.LoadAll();

            AsyncOperation async = Application.LoadLevelAsync("main");
            Debug.Log (async.progress);
            yield return async;

            bundle.Unload(false);
        }
}
```

Comment: At which line does the error occur? Is level `main` contained in the bundle?

Comment: I 'resolved'(NOT) the problem. In Unity 4.1.2 loading a scene from AssetBundle crashes when I stop the game. More details here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/382154/problem-in-loading-scene-from-asset-bundle.html#comment-469348 and here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/373556/how-can-i-stop-my-editor-from-crashing-everytime-i.html

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to use Unload() function clear the cache after asset bundle is used:-

```
Caching.CleanCache();
```

And every things will work fine but you have to download the asset bundle every time as you clearing out the cache after bundle use.

Or you can do this way

First of all call *DoNotDestroyOnLoad()* (for keeping the reference through out) function in Start() function and make a static variable to store a reference of the asset bundle when you use  *WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload* to download the asset,assign the reference to the static variable and unload the asset after its use. if you don not unload the asset bundle and use WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload again the same error will be thrown as you have stated.

Suppose if you loaded a scene using asset bundle then before quitting the scene unload the asset bundle reference stored in that static variable. That is why static variable is used so that we can access it from any script and unload it whenever we want also be careful about version.

```
class LoadScene:MonoBehaviour{
 ***public static AssetBundle refrenceOfAsset;***
 private AssetBundle assetBundle;

void Start(){
***DoNotDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);*** }
protected IEnumerator LoadTheScene()
{
    if (!Caching.IsVersionCached(url, version)){
        WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(url, version);
        yeild return www;  assetBundle = www.assetBundle;
        ***refrenceOfAsset = assetBundle;*** 
        www.Dispose();
        // Do what ever you want to do with the asset bundle but do not for get to unload it 
        refrenceOfAsset.Unload(true);
        }
    }
    else{
        Debug.Log("Asset Already Cached...");
        if(refrenceOfAsset!=null)
        refrenceOfAsset.Unload(true);
    }

}
```

or

or you can visit unity http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/keepingtrackofloadedassetbundles.html